# Multitenancy, Hibernate 4.3, Wildfly 9, Hikaricp autocommit mode false with ejb3 JTA container managed transactions and dao

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly, jta

We are using hibernate 4.3 multiTenancy, hikaricp connection provider:

```
  <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE"/>
  <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="multitenancy.HikariTenantConnectionProvider"/>
  <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="multitenancy.ThreadLocalIdentifierResolver"/>
```

In all cases we want that container is managing our transactions using java ee ejb standard.

PROBLEMS:

Autocommit

In auto commit mode following process happen lets say that we have following code in dao pattern voucherService:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
private Voucher save(Voucher entity, Boolean isCreate) throws Exception {

        voucherPoolService.save(entity);

        List<VoucherTag> tags = _detachTags(entity);
        List<VoucherCaption> captions = _detachCaptions(entity);

        if (isCreate) {
          voucherDAO.save(entity);
        } else {
          voucherDAO.merge(entity);
        }

        retailerService.updateTime(entity);

        _clearCollections(entity);
        _attachTags(entity, tags);
        _attachCaptions(entity, captions);

        voucherDAO.merge(entity);

        return entity;
}
```

Rest call:

```
  @POST
  @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackOn = {Exception.class})
  public Voucher create(Voucher entity) throws Exception {
    if (getValidator() != null) {
      getValidator().validateCreate(entity);
    }
    return getService().save(entity, true); // create
  }
```

How this will be processed in autocommit mode:

CONTAINER -> JTA transaction -> JDBC

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO voucher_pool ...
COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO voucher ...
COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO retailer ...
COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO voucher_tags ...
COMMIT;


START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO voucher_tags ...
COMMIT;
```

Problems ?:

If one of entity service throws sql exception for example on line:

```
  retailerService.updateTime(entity);
```

JTA transaction api will rollback, at that point there is no way to rollback :

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO voucher_pool ...
COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO voucher ...
COMMIT;
```

Because thy are already committed in database as separate jdbc tranasactions. 
How to handle this in a nice way ?

Answer (score 1):

Solutions ? 
Autocomit false

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
```

There is one big problem with it you have to explicitly say on each implementation when to commit example dao manual commit implementation:

```
public void commit() throws Exception {
    Session session = getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
    Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
    if (tx.isActive()) {
        session.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                connection.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Usage of it:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
private Voucher save(Voucher entity, Boolean isCreate) throws Exception {

        voucherPoolService.save(entity);

        List<VoucherTag> tags = _detachTags(entity);
        List<VoucherCaption> captions = _detachCaptions(entity);

        if (isCreate) {
          voucherDAO.save(entity);
        } else {
          voucherDAO.merge(entity);
        }

        retailerService.updateTime(entity);

        _clearCollections(entity);
        _attachTags(entity, tags);
        _attachCaptions(entity, captions);

        voucherDAO.merge(entity);
        // you have to explicitly say when to commit
        getDao().commit();

        return entity;
}
```

You would ask your self why i don't put it in generic dao implementation ? 
But you will end up in same situation as autocommit mode and you don't wan't that.

Luckily i have nice solution using hibernate interceptors which will handle that without explicitly defining a:

```
getDao().commit();
```

Here is persistance-unit example of your persistance.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="webservices" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>Your entitys here</class>
<class>Your entitys here</class>
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.use_outer_join" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
              value="com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction"/>

    <property name="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"
              value="webservices.dao.transaction.TransactionInterceptor"/>

    <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE"/>
    <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"
              value="webservices.multitenancy.HikariTenantConnectionProvider"/>
    <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver"
              value="webservices.multitenancy.ThreadLocalIdentifierResolver"/>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>

    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
              value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="true"/>

    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="30"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold" value="10000"/>
    <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="webservicesEMF"/>
    <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="webservicesEM"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="300000"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.transactionIsolation" value="TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE"/>

</properties>
```

Generic dao parts:

```
@Stateless
public class GenericDAO<E, ID extends Serializable> extends GenericDAOImpl<E, ID> {

  private Class<E> entityClass;
  private Class<ID> idClass;

  protected static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(GenericDAO.class);

  @PersistenceContext(name = "webservices")
  protected EntityManager em;

  private static final JPASearchProcessor searchProcessor = new JPASearchProcessor(new JPAAnnotationMetadataUtil());

  public GenericDAO() {
    super();
    entityClass = (Class<E>) DAOUtil.getTypeArguments(GenericDAOImpl.class, this.getClass()).get(0);
    init();
  }

  @PostConstruct
  protected void initialize() {
    setEntityManager(em);
    setSearchProcessor(searchProcessor);
  }
```

DAORegistry parts:

```
@Stateless
public class DAORegistry {

   public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
     EntityManager em = null;
     try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        em = (EntityManager) ic.lookup("webservicesEM");
     } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return em;
   }
```

AND THE MAGIC TRICK:

Apply interceptor:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="webservices.dao.transaction.TransactionInterceptor"/>
```

And your interceptor implementation:

```
public class TransactionInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

@Override
public void beforeTransactionCompletion(Transaction noTx) {
    DAORegistry.getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
    Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
    if (tx.isActive() && !tx.wasRolledBack() && !tx.wasCommitted()){
          session.doWork(Connection::commit);
    }

}
```

Now you don't need any more manual commit implementation:

```
 getDao().commit();
```

Your dao code will work anywhere as expected with nice JTA CMT implementation. Code below will work like a charm:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
private Voucher save(Voucher entity, Boolean isCreate) throws Exception {

    voucherPoolService.save(entity);

    List<VoucherTag> tags = _detachTags(entity);
    List<VoucherCaption> captions = _detachCaptions(entity);

    if (isCreate) {
        voucherDAO.save(entity);
    } else {
        voucherDAO.merge(entity);
    }

    retailerService.updateTime(entity);

    _clearCollections(entity);
    _attachTags(entity, tags);
    _attachCaptions(entity, captions);

    voucherDAO.merge(entity);

    return entity;
}
```

For more then a week I was searching for some example which will provide me such a nice implementation and i could not find it so i want to share my learnings.

Now you can use your EJB3 standard as you expected it should work,

Leave me your comments and learnings below. :)